# How can I use a custom CursorAdapter with AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a custom `CursorAdapter` (by inheriting from `CursorAdapter`) overriding `bindView(...)` and `newView(...)` as suggested here ([examplecursoradapter](http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/)).

However, when using it with an `AutoCompleteTextView`, the auto-completed value (i.e. the value entered when the user selects a value from the drop down list) inserted is the `toString()` value of the `SqliteCursor`. How can I obtain the value in the drop-down list, using this method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need to define `convertToString(Cursor)` method for your custom CursorAdapter.

For example:

```
public static class YourAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable{
    //bindView(), newView() etc...


    @Override
    public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        //returns string inserted into textview after item from drop-down list is selected.
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NAME_OF_COLUMN_DISPLAYED_IN_DROP_DOWN));
    }
}
```

You can also check examples from ApiDemos(files AutoComplete4.java and AutoComplete5.java  from `<android-sdk-dir>\samples\android-15\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view`